# Why is Elastic Beanstalk Traffic Splitting deploy strategy ignoring HTTP errors?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, traffic

I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. In there, I selected a Traffic Splitting deploy strategy, with a 100% split (so that 100% of new instances will have the new version and have their health evaluated).

Here's how (according to their documentation) that is supposed to work:

> During a traffic-splitting deployment, Elastic Beanstalk creates a new set of instances in a separate temporary Auto Scaling group. Elastic Beanstalk then instructs the load balancer to direct a certain percentage of your environment's incoming traffic to the new instances. Then, for a configured amount of time, Elastic Beanstalk tracks the health of the new set of instances. If all is well, Elastic Beanstalk shifts remaining traffic to the new instances and attaches them to the environment's original Auto Scaling group, replacing the old instances. Then Elastic Beanstalk cleans up—terminates the old instances and removes the temporary Auto Scaling group.

And more specifically:

> Rolling back the deployment to the previous application version is quick and doesn't impact service to client traffic. If the new instances don't pass health checks, or if you choose to abort the deployment, Elastic Beanstalk moves traffic back to the old instances and terminates the new ones.

However, it seems silly that it *only* looks at my internal `/health` health checks, and not the overall health status of the environment, from the HTTP status codes, that it already has information on.

I tried the following scenario:

1. Deploy a new version.
2. As soon as the "health evaluation period" begins, flood the server with error 500s (from an endpoint I made specifically for this purpose).
3. AWS then moves all my instances into "degraded" state, and "unhealthy", but then seems to ignore it, and goes on anyway.

See the following two log dump screenshots (they are oldest-first).

Is there any way that I can make AWS respect the HTTP status based health checks that it already performs, during a traffic split? Or am I bound to only rely on custom-developed health checks entirely?

**Update 1:** Even weirder, I tried making my own healthchecks fail always too, but it still decides to deploy the new version with the failed healthcheck!

**Update 2:** I noticed that the temporary auto scaling group that it creates while assessing health does only have an "EC2" type health check, and not "ELB". I think that might be the root cause. If I could only get it to use "ELB" instead.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is interesting! I do not know if setting the health check type to "ELB" may do the job because we use CodeDeploy, which has far better rollback capabilities than AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

However, there is a well-document way in the docs [1] to apply the setting you are looking for:

> [...] By default, the Auto Scaling group, created for your environment uses Amazon EC2 status checks. If an instance in your environment fails an Amazon EC2 status check, Auto Scaling takes it down and replaces it.
> Amazon EC2 status checks only cover an instance's health, not the health of your application, server, or any Docker containers running on the instance. If your application crashes, but the instance that it runs on is still healthy, it may be kicked out of the load balancer, but Auto Scaling won't replace it automatically. [...]
> If you want Auto Scaling to replace instances whose application has stopped responding, you can use a configuration file to configure the Auto Scaling group to use Elastic Load Balancing health checks. The following example sets the group to use the load balancer's health checks, in addition to the Amazon EC2 status check, to determine an instance's health.

> Example .ebextensions/autoscaling.config
>
> ```yaml
> Resources:
>  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
>    Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
>    Properties:
>      HealthCheckType: ELB
>      HealthCheckGracePeriod: 300
> ```

It does not mention the new traffic splitting deployment feature, though.
Thus, I cannot confirm this is the actual solution, but at least you can give it a shot.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environmentconfig-autoscaling-healthchecktype.html

Comment: Yeah, I tried that configuration. It does indeed apply to the permanent auto scaling group, but not the temporary one it uses to assess health.

Comment: Mhhh that is interesting! Is the temporary asg visible in the cloud formation template which is managed by elastic beanstalk?

Comment: Hmmm, there is one visible there. But is it considered a good idea to modify that directly? Doesn't feel right.

Comment: Could you try to modify it using the .ebextensions file above by changing "AWSEBAutoScalingGroup" to the logical ID of that "temporary" ASG?

Comment: Ah that's what you mean. Sorry, I misunderstood. Only `AWSEBAutoScalingGroup` is visible in the Cloudformation template.

Comment: That is unfortunate. I have no idea how to solve that otherwise. Since this is a relatively new feature which I did not use myself, I do not fully understand what AWS is doing under the hood. Not being able to modify the temporary ASG seems like a bad design decision to me. However, if the temporary asg has a predictable id or tag, you could change the health check type on every deployment programmatically via a cli call (which is triggered by CloudWatch events)

Comment: I just realized that another workaround might be to react to the elastic beanstalk events via EventBridge and a lambda function: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.eventbridge.html

Comment: This all just seems incredibly complicated for something that (in my opinion) should be quite simple. I contacted support for this, to see if they have an error on their end. Thank you for your help so far. I upvoted your post, and all of your comments.

Comment: Good luck! Please post the solution if there is a good one from the AWS side. =)

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time I thought that the Immutable Deployment option in Elastic Beanstalk was a holy panacea -- but it only works when a deployment involves no changes to the application's database schema.

We've now resorted to blue-green deployments. However, this only works if you control the DNS. If you are a SaaS solution and you allow customers to create a CNAME then B/G is often a spectacular failure as the enterprise: a) sets a very high TTL, and/or b) their internal DNS or firewalls caches the underlaying IP addresses of the ALB (which are dynamic and, of course, replaced when you swap the URL of the blue and green environments).

Answer (score 0):

Traffic splitting is written as an option in the Elastic Beanstalk documentation.

[image]

But it's not actually an option in the configuration section in the console.

[image]

This wouldn't be the first time I've seen Elastic Beanstalk's docs are out of date so it could be AWS have removed that feature.

Since AWS introduced CodeStar I suspect Elastic Beanstalk is getting the cold shoulder.